# Conditional formatting slow on big selection

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am using conditional formatting to create a poor man's gantt chart. The idea is to have the first column have the task, the second have the duration, and the third have the resource. Each of the 7 resources have their own color. Columns 4-100ish have conditional formatting applied to them such that when there is a character in a cell, upon exit, the cell takes on the color of that row's 3rd column. I accomplish this with the following formula...

```
=(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),3))="Resource A")*(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()))<>"")
```

I have 7 conditional formatting lines, one for each resource/color, all with Stop If True checked.

Each rule is applied to the entire grid, in this case `=$H$6:$HI$93`

My problem is this is really slow. If I enter a dash into the cell, it will take about 2 seconds for Excel to finish applying the conditional formatting.

Any suggestions on how to speed this formatting up other than the obvious...use less rules.

Comment: That formula looks like it could boil down to `=and($c6="Resource A", h6<>"")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work as a rule, taking advantage of the way CF uses cell references in formulas:

```
 =AND(H6<>"", $C6="Resource A")
```

Where H6 is the top-left cell in the range being formatted (make sure to select the range from the top-left). The `$C6` will allow the row to change but the column will remain fixed.